# Перемещение изображения по канвасу

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, canvas

Будьте добры, помогите наладить перемещение изображения карты города по канвасу. На данный момент, видимо, функция перемещения не запоминает измененных координат изображения.

Код и его отображение тут:http://codepen.io/eviiil/pen/VmjPjp (Дождитесь, пока изображение загрузится на канвасе).

```
var isMoving = false;
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
 // event - объект события, в нем много интересной фигни
 // попробуй console.log(event) и увидишь

 // event.pageX, event.pageY - координаты `места` события
 console.log(event.pageX);
 console.log(event.pageY);
 isMoving = true;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
 isMoving = false;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  if (isMoving) {
    moveIm(event.pageX, event.pageY);
  };

function moveIm(dx,dy){
x0=dx;
y0=dy;
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, но

```
var saveX = undefined, saveY = undefined;

if(saveX!==undefined && saveY!==undefined)
{
x = saveX;
y = saveY;
}

ELEMENT.onmouseout = function()
{
   saveX = x //или другая переменная которая используется для отрисовки
   saveY = y //аналогично
}
```

Данный код может не работать, всего лишь идея для реализации, поэкспериментируй с этим.

Comment: Суть в том что тут нужно применять `onmouseout` обязательно, и отрисовку карты можно заменить с помощью `onmousemove`